# Facebook Graph API, mark inbox as read?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Okay I think the title pretty much sums it up but I'll explain my situation anyway. I have written a desktop app using the Facebook C# SDK and Graph API which notifys me when I have new notifications and new (unread) messages in my inbox and it seems to work but the facebook graph api even when I use Facebooks Graph API explorer to get /me/inbox (this is specific to my facebook account) has an inbox thread that is marked as unread but does not show up on facebooks website or any of the Facebook apps i use (android/iPhone) so I can see in the api explorer everything about the thread and theres a message under the "message" field but doesn't have anything in "comments". Anyway my problem is when I use this new app i've written this keep showing up and as it doesnt show in messages on facebooks website or the facebook mobile apps, I cannot mark it as read. So is there a way to do this manually using the graph API even just so I can do it with the api explorer because I dont want it forever showing in my app, I know that i can mark notifications as read this way but I cannot work out how to mark this inbox thread as read. I could always hardcode the thread id into my app and tell it to ignore it but this is an extremely unelegant solution especially considering I am not the only person who will use this app. Even a way to delete the thread completely by graph API, is this possible?

EDIT: I have tried POST https://graph.facebook.com/(thread_id) with fields "unread": 0 but that did not work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263262/facebook-api-mark-notification-as-read

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no permissions in the current APIs that Facebook has available other than Read-Only access to a user's Inbox.