# How mark a Facebook notification as read via Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-fql

I have managed to get a list of new Facebook `Notifications` but can't seem to find a way of marking them as read?

I am using `FQL` with the `PHP SDK`.

Please can someone point me to some documentation with examples.

Answer (score 3):

To mark a notification as read, POST to

```
graph.facebook.com/NOTIFICATION_ID
```

with param `"unread"=0`.

If you've received the notification object via Grapth API, NOTIFICATION_ID equals the id of the notification object.

If you've received the notification object via FQL, you'll have to build NOTIFICATION_ID as follows:

```
"Notif_" + userId + "_" + notification_id.
```

For example if current userId is 123 and notification_id from FQL is 456, NOTIFICATION_ID should be:

```
notif_123_456
```

and the POST becomes:

```
graph.facebook.com/notif_123_456
```

with parameter `unread=0`

You'll need 'manage_notifications' permission.

Comment: Also we can send DELETE graph.facebook.com/NOTIFICATION_ID without any params.

Comment: Update: something changed. Now work only POST request.

Answer (score 1):

To read notifications, you will need to get `manage_notifications` permission from the user. (Presuming you already have that is you can getList).

To mark a notification as read you need to use:

`notifications.markRead`

You can find information on this page.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.markRead/

You cannot use straight FQL to mark a notification as read and you can only mark notifications that have been created (as I am led to believe) during the current user session.

Comment: ah so I have to use the old rest api :(
Do I just use file_get_contents to call the api?

Comment: CURL is going to be the best way. Just send a request to the endpoint in that link.