# Mark a notification as read in Facebook graph API

Tags: angularjs, facebook-graph-api, notifications, http-request

I am willing to mark a user's notification as read using the facebook graph api, but I am now starting to wonder if that is possible at all. Here is what I am trying now, which is a solution I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263262/how-mark-a-facebook-notification-as-read-via-facebook-api) question on stackoverflow.

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + item.id + '?unread=0'}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              // this callback will be called asynchronously
              // when the response is available
              deferred.resolve(status);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              // called asynchronously if an error occurs
              // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
```

Of course, `item.id` is the id of the notification.

I am using angular for my http requests, but I dont mind other methods too, just angular's is the easiest for me. I am also looking forward to hear any ideas on how to mark notifications as read, I don't prefer any way, just want it to happen somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found a while ago, forgot to post. (Note that I am using angular.js, if you are not either make the promise with q or rsvp libraries or don't)

```
function (notificationId) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    FB.api(
        'https://graph.facebook.com/' + notificationId, 'post', {
        unread: 0
    },

    function (response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            deferred.reject(response.error);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```